# How to release an object in ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Although I usually ARC mode in Xcode, but sometimes, I still need to release some temp obj. I don't know how to use it. Here is a example:

TestViewController.h file

```
TestViewController
{
    A* a;
    A* b;
}
```

TestViewController.m file

```
viewDidLoad()
{
   a = [[A alloc] init];
   b = a;

   [a release];
   // I want to release a here, but when I use [a release], there will be a build error. "release is unavailable: not available in ARC mode"
}
```

Can anyone give me some clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC will take care of this for you. There is no reason to manually release `a`. Doing so would be incorrect anyway, since `a` still points to the object.

But you should still not directly access your ivars this way. While ARC will do the right thing (more on that in a second), it causes many other problems. Always use accessors except in `init` and `dealloc`. This should be:

```
@interface TestViewController
@property (readwrite, strong) A* a;
@property (readwrite, strong) A* b;
@end

@implementation TestViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.a = [[A alloc] init];
    self.b = self.a;
}
```

As for what ARC is actually doing in your code, it will insert the required retains something like this:

```
A* tmp = [[a alloc] init];
[a release];
a = tmp;
A* tmp2 = [a retain];
[b release];
b = tmp2;
```

If you don't want `a` to point to the old value, then set it to `nil` as Michael notes. This has nothing to do with retains and releases. Focus on the object graph. What do you want each thing to point to? ARC will take care of the retain counts.

Comment: Hi Rob, my question is if [a release]; then how can we assign a = temp as a retain count is 0 once it is release. can you please explain?

Comment: @HardikMamtora "a" is just a pointer to an object. "a = tmp" causes it to point to a different object. "a" itself doesn't have a retain count. Objects do. Pointers point to objects.

Answer (score 2):

`a = nil;` should do what you are trying to do.

However, the object that you created will be assigned to `b` and retained by `b`.