# UIAlertView Without ARC

Tags: ios

How can I create a UIAlertView without using automatic reference counting in my app? The problem I am having is the [Alert release]; part since release cannot be used in automatic reference counting.

Comment: So are you using ARC or not? Your question seems to contradict itself. What specific problem is `release` giving you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to release a obj in ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675395/how-to-release-a-obj-in-arc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use alert release at all - it's not necessary with ARC.  [alert show]; may be what you're looking for:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init…];
[alert show];
```

That's it.

Comment: @user2921081 Glad I could help.  Have fun.